# Installed Boost module. How do you tell it is working on your site?

Tags: 7, caching

I just installed the Boost module on Drupal 7 and activated everything properly. How do I even tell if its working properly?

Comment: Option 1: You can check the Drupal Status Report for your Boost installation in  Administer > Reports > Status report (admin/reports/status). Option 2:  Also, open your web page source code. Scroll down to the last line. It will show how long your page has been cached by boost module.

Answer (score 2):

View the source code of the page as you're browsing as an anonymous user. Boost inserts [some metadata](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/boost/tree/boost.module?h=7.x-1.1#n327) about the cached page ("Page cached by...") as an HTML comment:

```
  // Add note to bottom of content if possible.
  if ($_boost['matched_header_info']['comment_start'] && $_boost['matched_header_info']['comment_end']) {
    $expire = $_boost['matched_header_info']['lifetime_max'];
    $cached_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', REQUEST_TIME);
    $expires_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', REQUEST_TIME + $expire);
    $note = "\n" . $_boost['matched_header_info']['comment_start'] . 'Page cached by Boost @ ' . $cached_at . ', expires @ ' . $expires_at . ', lifetime ' . format_interval($expire) . $_boost['matched_header_info']['comment_end'];
    $data .= $note;
  }
```